# How to document a tuple with different data types using drf-spectacular?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-spectacular

I'm using drf-spectacular to generate a Swagger documentation.

I have a viewset that returns a dict (it doesn't go through a drf serializer as it's all native objects).

The dict looks like this:

```py
data = {
            "lines": List[str],
            "points": List[Tuple[float, float, int, str]]
            "next_failure_date": str,
            "estimate_nth_failure": str
            "status": str,
        }
```

I can't find a way for drf-spectacular to properly document the "points" key, it only gives me a

```
"points": ["string"]
```

What I tried :

```py
class SwaggerGrowthChartPoint:
    """Class used to generate the Swagger documentation"""

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, sap_id: int, created_on: str):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sap_id = sap_id
        self.created_on = created_on

class SwaggerGrowthChartPointField(serializers.Field):

    def to_representation(self, value: SwaggerGrowthChartPoint):
        return f"{value.x}, {value.y}, {value.sap_id}, {value.created_on}"
    
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return SwaggerGrowthChartPoint(*data)

class SwaggerGrowthChartSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer used to generate the Swagger documentation"""

    lines = SwaggerGrowthChartLinesSerializer(many=True)
    points = serializers.ListField(child=SwaggerGrowthChartPointField())
    next_failure_date = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DateField())
    estimate_nth_failure = serializers.DateField()
    status = serializers.CharField()
```

But no luck.

Comment: Have you solved it in the end? I have the same problem

Comment: @LiaVa Sorry, I added a comment in the docs about it but could type it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to partially solve the problem for me:

```py
@extend_schema_field(
    {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "oneOf": [
                {"type": "string"},
                {"type": "integer"},
            ],
        },
        "description": "A time point and its availability state",
        "example": '["00:00", 1]',
    }
)
class TimePointAvailabilityField(serializers.Field):
    pass

class DetailedScheduleItem(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField()
    schedule = serializers.ListField(child=TimePointAvailabilityField())
```

At least, it generates the right JSON example:

```json
  {
    "date": "2023-11-21",
    "schedule": [
      [
        "00:00",
        1
      ]
    ]
  }
```

And you can avoid the field type altogether if you need only the example, since it's enough for the schema to have example value to generate it.